# Reduccion en haskell

Tags: haskell

Estoy tratando de reducir esta función, muchas gracias

```
 funcionPractica x f = \g -> h ( g x )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por un lado, hay una equivalencia entre una función y una expresión *lambda*. Estas dos sentencias son equivalentes:

```hs
f = \x -> h

f x = h
```

Lo que nos daría la primera reducción:

```hs
func x f g = h ( g x )
       where h = \z -> f z
```

Por otro lado, la expresión lambda de la cláusula where no es otra cosa que la aplicación de la función `f`. Por tanto, podemos sustituir `h` por `f`:

```hs
func x f g = f ( g x )
```

O sea, se trata de la composición de dos funciones, `f` y `g`. Para que quede claro, mejor usar el operador composición:

```hs
func x f g = (f . g)  x
```

Ésta sería la solución más sencilla y que dejaría como final. Pero dependiendo de lo que consideres por *simple*, aún se podría simplificar más transformando esta función en una expresión *pointfree*, bastante más difícil de entender:

```hs
func = flip (.) . flip id
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Chema, me sirvió y mucho. Te puedo hacer otra consulta sobre composición?

Comment: Este foro está abierto a todo el mundo. Haz tu pregunta y te ayudaremos en lo que podamos. Eso sí, intenta hacer una entrada por pregunta.

Comment: Chema, te comparto el link de mi consulta                      
                      https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/376906/composici%c3%b3n-en-haskell