# Composición en Haskell

Tags: funciones, haskell

Resolví este ejercicio en `Haskell`. Ahora lo tengo que hacer sin recursión, y usando composición de funciones predefinidas.

```
ConLongitud :: Int -> [String] -> Int
ConLongitud _ [] = 0
ConLongitud n (x:xs)
| n == length x = 1 + ConLongitud n xs
| otherwise = ConLongitud n xs
```

Comment: probablemente quieras mirar a `filter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Básicamente, lo que hace esta función es contar las cadenas que tienen una longitud especificada. Lo primero es filtrar la lista de cadenas a las que tengan la longitud buscada y luego contarlas:

```hs
conLongitud :: Int -> [String] -> Int
conLongitud n xs = length ys
  where ys = [x | for x in xs, length x == n]
```

Pero el problema te dice *"composición de funciones"*. En lugar de usar una *compresión de listas* se podría usar `filter`, algo así:

```hs
ys = filter (n==) (map length xs)
```

Esta definición recorre la lista dos veces, una para calcular la longitud de todas las cadenas y otra vez para filtrar. Se puede hacer en un paso:

```hs
ys = filter (\s -> n == length s) xs
```

O en *pointfree*:

```hs
ys = filter ((n==) . length) xs
```

Con ello obtendríamos la definición final:

```hs
conLongitud :: Int -> [String] -> Int
conLongitud n = length . filter ((n==) . length)
```

El contaje de elementos suele ser muy habitual. No existe una función estándar para ello, por lo que es habitual definir una:

```hs
count :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Int
count pred = length . filter pred

conLongitud :: Int -> [String] -> Int
conLongitud n = count ((n==) . length)
```